# How to write a trigger that should execute every day at 00:00 am?

Tags: sql-server-2005, datetime, triggers

I want to write a trigger that should execute beginning of the every date based on the server datetime. In that I want to update one table such as follow:

```
  UPDATE STR_IRSHeader SET StatusID = 4
  WHERE GETDATE()>ExpiryDate.
```

How to write a trigger for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a trigger, but job.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191439.aspx

Comment: I couldnt find sql agent in my SQL Server Management Studio Express and SQL Server Configuration Manager. Where it is?

Comment: @gbn, well, per MS: "SQL-DMO will be removed in the next version of Microsoft SQL Server." see details there http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms135739.aspx - also this include way how to create job in script-like way

Answer (score 1):

You could create a shell script and then set up a cron job to run every day at midnight?

Comment: On a Windows box running SQL Server?

Comment: I couldnt find sql agent in my SQL Server Management Studio Express and SQL Server Configuration Manager. Where it is?

Answer (score 1):

Triggers are not scheduled by time.
SQL triggers are invoked by actions that change data (UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE, ALTER etc)

You should use a [SQL Server Agent job](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190268.aspx) to run [the SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187910.aspx) you want.

Your SQL can be wrapped in a stored procedure too: this allows you to run it manually and have the exact code in one place: less chance of mistakes or multiple versions of the code

Comment: I couldnt find sql agent in my SQL Server Management Studio Express and SQL Server Configuration Manager. Where it is?